# Yahoo is treating my email address as a separate account, how can I merge the accounts?

Tags: yahoo, yahoo-fantasy-sports

I have a Yahoo account:  myYahooAccount@yahoo.com.  A year or so ago, I changed the primary email address on the account to myNewEmail@gmail.com.

From then on, I always logged into my Yahoo! account using myNewEmail@gmail.com.

Recently, Yahoo! brought the option to sign in using Google.  I assumed that signing in with myNewEmail@gmail.com meant it would sign me into my existing Yahoo account.  Alas, it did not, and it created a totally separate account with the same email address.

A day or so later, a friend sent me an invite to a fantasy league to myNewEmail@gmail.com.  I clicked it and joined, but it was linked to my "Google sign on" account, not the original Yahoo! account like all my other leagues.

Now, I'm stuck with two accounts, with one league that I can only access by signing in through Google, and the other leagues all in my original Yahoo account.

What is my fix here?  I've scoured the Yahoo help files, and obviously they are of zero use.  I even tried to set my two accounts as "co-managers" of the fantasy leagues but unfortunately it looks like the help file on that one is outdated, the "edit team settings" is no longer available.

What are my options?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a bug in Yahoo!. You cannot do anything about it, other than writing to Yahoo!

Comment: +1, probably the best option to just contact Yahoo and explain them what has happened. If it was a bug, they will want to know anyway; so they can solve it.

Comment: No luck, zero response.